# Python watchdog. Need to know the observer

Tags: python, watchdog

I'm using same event handler for multiple watchdog observers. I need to know, event is generated for which observer when file/dir is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tag such as an observer name when you create the event.  Python events can have almost any type of data added as named members and then access by the handler.